# Stripe API (PHP) & Parse

Tags: php, ios, swift, parse-platform, stripe-payments

I am building an app on iOS in swift and I am accepting payments using stripe. I have created a form that creates a customer and upon a successful save I call back the customerID and save it into my Parse Database.

Below is the code for the above:

XCODE:

```
    let myCustomerID = user!.valueForKey("secretID") as! String
    self.sendTokenToServer(myCustomerID, myAmount: cost)

    func sendTokenToServer(aCustomer: String, myAmount: String) {
    var theamount = myAmount
    //  SEND REQUEST TO PHP FILE IN WEBSERVER
    let url = NSURL(string: ".../cutomeragain.php")
    var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    let body = "custID=\(aCustomer)&amount=\(theamount)"
    request.HTTPBody = body.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)

    //  SEND ASYNCHORNOUS REQUEST
    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) {
        (response, data, error) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
        }
     }
```

When I go to charge the customer by ID, it does not accept the charge. Below is the PHP code:

```
    <?php

    require_once('stripe-php/init.php');

    \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('xxx');

    // Get the credit card details submitted by the form
    $amount = $_POST['amount'];
    $customerId = $_POST['custID'];
    $cutomer = \Stripe\Customer::retrieve('custID');

    // Charge the Customer instead of the card
    $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
    "amount" => $amount, 
    "currency" => "usd",
    "customer" => $customerId)
    );

    // create a json output with completion variable, (this will be read from    the ios app as response)
    $json = array(
    'completion' => 'done',
    'completion1' => $cutomerId,
    'ok' => $cutomer-id
    );
    echo json_encode($json);

    ?>
```

Am I missing something in my PHP file? I've tried a number of different methods. I.e. retrieving the customer from Stripe using

Comment: what do you mean by does not accept the charge, what error do you get?

Comment: It did not return an error. The call to the web services would be successful, however, the charge would not post to Stripe.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I figured it out. I had to play around a bit, however, I think that someone else will find this useful.

In my xcode file I changed

```
    let myCustomerID = user!.valueForKey("secretID") as! String
```

to

```
    let myCustomerID = user?["secretID"] as? String
```

In my PHP file I changed the code to the following:

```
    // Get the credit card details submitted by the form
    $amount = $_POST['amount'];
    $customerId = $_POST['cus'];
    $cu = \Stripe\Customer::retrieve($customerId);

    // Charge the Customer instead of the card
    $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
    "amount" => $amount, 
    "currency" => "usd",
    "customer" => $customerId,)
    );

    // create a json output with completion variable, (this will be read from      the ios app as response)
   $json = array(
   'completion' => 'done',
   'completion1' => $cutomerId,
   'ok' => $cutomer-id
   );
   echo json_encode($json);

   ?>
```